# Are there VPN,API, VPN, SFTP, Cloud or another possibility to build connection between two remote SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm totally new in SQL Server. But I'm going to work on it from now.

I have been asked to research five methods to copy or access data from one remote SQL server(Location A) to another remote SQL server(Location B).

I found several method to achieve this goal, such as Linked Server, Openrowset
T-SQL function and SSIS(SQL Server Integration Service).

But are there API, VPN, SFTP, Cloud or another possibility to achieve this goal?
Your answer will be really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You dnt need to access any other method just make sure Location A Ip and port address is open in the firewall.

Also Location B Server should be accessible to location A

Access server You need below details:

ServerName with Port no
Database Id and Password.

Copy the data from A to B please see below:

you can generate the table script from server A run the same script on Table B.

> If you want the Table with data from A then during the script
> generation in last window where you need to select patch for script
> file Just click on Advance option and then their select the Schema
> type as Schema and Data then it will generate the Data script as well
> for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IP and port address are used to build connection. But how can i access the data, such as copy a table from SQL Server A to SQL server B automatically?

Comment: You can use an INSERT INTO from server A to server B, using linked server or openrowset/opendatasource. You can also put this INSERT INTO inside a Stored Proceure which could be called by a job several times a day... You can do things... You could also use SSIS as you said in your post. For more help you should be more specific.

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you. But just get new information from Server B(destination). There is no firewall,only a simple router / modem for private individuals.